# CSS classes not changing when I replace them in a function?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make the site title and description that is displayed on the homepage have the same styling as the page title and descriptions on all the other pages but I'm having some issues. Here is the original function that displays the site title and description:

```
/**
 * Displays Site Title and Site Description.
 */
function integer_site_title() {
    $class = 'site-branding__copy';

    if ( 0 == get_theme_mod( 'header_text', 1 ) ) {
        $class .= ' screen-reader-text';
    }

    printf( '<div class="%s">', esc_attr( $class ) );

        if ( is_front_page() && is_home() && get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) {
            printf( '<h1 class="site-title"><a href="%s" rel="home">%s</a></h1>',
                esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
                esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )
            );
        } elseif ( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) {
            printf( '<p class="site-title"><a href="%s" rel="home">%s</a></p>',
                esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
                esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )
            );
        }

        if ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) {
            printf( '<p class="site-description">%s</p>', esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) );
        }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

The page title and descriptions on the other pages have the class names, `page-header__title` and `page-header__description.` So, I thought that if I just changed the code for the site title/description to this:

```
function integer_site_title() {
    $class = 'site-branding__copy';

    if ( 0 == get_theme_mod( 'header_text', 1 ) ) {
        $class .= ' screen-reader-text';
    }

    printf( '<div class="%s">', esc_attr( $class ) );

        if ( is_front_page() && is_home() && get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) {
            printf( '<h1 class="page-header__title"><a href="%s" rel="home">%s</a></h1>',
                esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
                esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )
            );
        } elseif ( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) {
            printf( '<p class="page-header__title"><a href="%s" rel="home">%s</a></p>',
                esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
                esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) )
            );
        }

        if ( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) {
            printf( '<p class="page-header__description">%s</p>', esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'description' ) ) );
        }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

...it would apply the same styling but that didn't work. When I inspect the code, the class names didn't change even though I had changed them in the code. How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What happens instead? Have you made sure that the modified code is even run?

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, I mean that the classes don't change even though I changed them in the code. How can I see if it's being run or not?

Comment: @taylor018 You have several ways to check it, `var_dump($variable)` to show a value of a variable, `die('Message')` to kill the pageload and return back something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. The function wasn't running at all because I was calling it from the parent theme. I needed to create a new function in the child theme functions.php and call that instead of the function from the parent theme.